# In Elm, how can I detect if focus will be lost from a group of elements?

Tags: json, events, dom, elm

Suppose I have a form with a number of components. I'd like to detect a los of focus **from the group**. So, focus from 1 input to another on the same form should be ignored. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, we want to be able to tag each focusable element within the group with some attribute, so when we switch elements we'll know if we're in the same group or not. This can be achieved with data attributes.

```
groupIdAttribute groupId =
    Html.Attributes.attribute "data-group-id" groupId
```

Next, we need to decode the event payload on an `onBlur` event to see if the `target` is different from the `relatedTarget` (that which will get the focus). And report the change. (note that here we refer to `data-group-id` via the path `"dataset", "groupId"`)

```
decodeGroupIdChanged msg =
    Json.Decode.oneOf
        [ Json.Decode.map2
            (\a b ->
                if a /= b then
                    Just a

                else
                    Nothing
            )
            (Json.Decode.at [ "target", "dataset", "groupId" ] Json.Decode.string)
            (Json.Decode.at [ "relatedTarget", "dataset", "groupId" ] Json.Decode.string)
        , Json.Decode.at [ "target", "dataset", "groupId" ] Json.Decode.string
            |> Json.Decode.andThen (\a -> Json.Decode.succeed (Just a))
        ]
        |> Json.Decode.andThen
            (\maybeChanged ->
                case maybeChanged of
                    Just a ->
                        Json.Decode.succeed (msg a)

                    Nothing ->
                        Json.Decode.fail "no change"
            )
```

Now we can create an `onGroupLoss` listener:

```
onGroupFocusLoss msg =
    Html.Events.on "blur" (decodeGroupIdChanged msg)
```

And rig it up like so:

```
input [onGroupFocusLoss GroupFocusLoss, groupIdAttribute "a"]
```

Here is an example (note that it is built with elm-ui so there's a little extra code.)

https://ellie-app.com/3nkBCXJqjQTa1

Comment: You could probably use a `focusout` handler on an ancestor instead of attaching a `blur` handler on every input.

Comment: Interesting. This opens up other possible ways of doing this, but I'm not sure what the best option is. What I have is most flexible (e.g. suppose you have a control which pops up a sub-control that isn't part of the same tree, and you want to trigger a save if the group of controls, in general, loses focus). `focusout` could lead to cleaner code if we know all items are in the same hierarchy.

Comment: Wouldn't those have a different group id anyway?

Comment: I can imagine a UI where this would not be the case. That doesn't mean it's a great UI. So my solution solves more generally. Your solution is a better solution to a subset of use cases (which may or may not be better examples of UI design). I have to think about this for a bit.

Comment: Not sure I understand, since it seems to just compare group ids, not which blur handler is attached. Unless you mean they can have group ids without blur handlers, but then wouldn't that be a possibility for any relatedTarget too? Probably doesn't matter much either way though :)

Comment: So, we can have my `onComponentFocusLossWhichIsAlsoAGroupFocusLoss` and your `onChildFocusLossWhichIsAlsoAGroupFocusLoss`. I can do more specific things with the first. However, I think your solution is nicer in most realistic cases. I'm not sure what I should leave as a solution on SO.

Comment: It seems fine as it is, with "focusout" as just a comment or footnote. The differences are pretty subtle, though it might matter in some edge case or other :)